# Retaining Gridview hyperlink column after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, postback

I have a hyperlink Gridview column created in code behind (gridView_RowDataBound) that turns into plain text on postabk. The text and NavigateUrl of the hyperlink are the value of cell[0] of the dynamically generated gridview.

```
` protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                link.Target = "blank";
                link.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                link.NavigateUrl = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }`
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with the RowCreated event to ensure the hyperlinks are retained on postback. But the data in the Gridview is lost so I can't access it the same way.

Comment: Remove the `IsPostBack` check when binding data to the GridView.

Comment: @VDWWD There is no IsPostBack when I data bind the Gridview. The RowCreated is called on each postBack so I'm trying to use it to recreate the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, here's what I ended up doing on every load of the page(postBack)

```
protected void GridViewDisplayDocument_RowCreated()
{
   var rowCount = GridViewDisplayDocument.Rows.Count;
   for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
   {
      var url = GridViewDisplayDocument.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
      if (url != string.Empty)
      {
         HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
         link.Target = "blank";
         link.Text = url;
         link.NavigateUrl =  url;

         GridViewDisplayDocument.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);
       }
    } 
}
```